# reguarding getting md5 of files in a directory with perl

Tags: perl, directory, md5

i have spent the last 3 days trying to figure out why i cannot get an single file in a directory to show. i can get md5 of any single file, but not if its in a directory.

this script will list the files, but it will not list the md5 of any of the files in the directory.

here is the code i am working with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $dirname = "./directory_name";
opendir( DIR, $dirname );
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

print "@files\n";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    if ( -d $file || !-r $file ) { next; }
    open( my $FILE, $file );
    print Digest::MD5->new->addfile($FILE)->hexdigest, " $file\n";
}
system ( 'pause' )
```

its a simple script to get md5's of each file in a directory and is very useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your error status `$!` of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) or include [`use autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) at the top of your script.  You're calling `open` but assuming it works.  Because you're missing path information for the files, it's likely that they aren't being found and are all being skipped by the [`-r`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) check.

One solution for getting the path info included is to just use a file [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) instead of [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Digest::MD5;

my $dirname = "./directory_name";

foreach my $file (<$dirname/*>) {
    next if -d $file;
    open( my $FILE, '<:raw', $file );
    print Digest::MD5->new->addfile($FILE)->hexdigest, " $file\n";
}
```

Additionally, be sure to `open` your files in [`:raw`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) or [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) or they may return incorrect values.

Comment: you sir are my hero lol, i knew it was something simple and i have spent the past few days trying to figure out why it wasnt working. thanks :)

Comment: i will add autodie to my scripts from now on, thanks again mr.miller

Comment: thanks for the tips, usually i do use binmode, but as i was trying to figure out what i was doing wrong, it was throwing errors about using binmode for some reason, thats why this is not included. but it is indeed giving me the correct checksums on everyfile. im using a well known hex editor to compare checksums to make sure. thanks for all the tips man :)